# GSM Modem with MAX232 to Arduino Serial?

Tags: gsm, max232

I have GSM modem that has MAX232 interface for RX/TX/GND on three pins.
Is it possible to interface Arduino in some way?

Tnx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with another MAX232, or bypass the MAX232 somehow.

Comment: Tnx, should lines be exchanged on another max232? rx,tx->tx,rx

Comment: Of course. Otherwise you'll be transmitting to a transmit pin, not a receive pin.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation, something else doesn't work :)